# radio buttons in react, ignore null value

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs, radio-button, jsx

so i'm developing a personality quiz app using one of the tutorials i found on the internet //mitchgavan.com/react-quiz/, I have a quizQuestions.js file for api where i fetch the answer and the question from, like so

```
{
question: "I am task oriented in order to achieve certain goals",
answers: [
  {
    type: "Brown",
    content: "Hell Ya!"
  },
  {
    type: " ",
    content: "Nah"
  }
]
},
```

it has type and content, so [this is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGSpJ.png) the initial state of the app, every time the user click on Hell YA button it will increment that type +1, for example Brown: 1 etc.. but the problem is, when user select Nah it will give me [this :null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0rgm.png) , I have a AnswerOption.js component like so

```
 function AnswerOption(props) {
  return (
    <AnswerOptionLi>
      <Input
        checked={props.answerType === props.answer}
        id={props.answerType}
        value={props.answerType}
        disabled={props.answer}
        onChange={props.onAnswerSelected}
      />
      <Label className="radioCustomLabel" htmlFor={props.answerType}>
        {props.answerContent}
      </Label>
    </AnswerOptionLi>
  );
}


AnswerOption.PropTypes = {
  answerType: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  answerContent: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  answer: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onAnswerSelected: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

and my setUserAnswer function like so

```
setUserAnswer(answer) {
    const updatedAnswersCount = update(this.state.answersCount, {
      [answer]: {$apply: (currentValue) => currentValue + 1}
    });
    this.setState({
      answersCount: updatedAnswersCount,
      answer: answer
    });
}
```

my question is, how can i let react ignore that white space, so when user click Nah it will not do anything with it, and if there is different approach to the problem i will be gladly accept it, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution to your problem is to check if answer is empty :

```
if(answer.trim()) {

    const updatedAnswersCount = update(this.state.answersCount, {
        [answer]: {$apply: (currentValue) => currentValue + 1}
    });
    this.setState({
      answersCount: updatedAnswersCount,
      answer: answer
    });

}
```

Comment: @Irfan , My pleasure!!